# How to sort a table horizontally

Tags: jquery

I am trying to sort a table horizontally.

The sorting consists of clicking the header and so the elements should get sorted.

I have tried the code below

But it doesn't sort it properly.
What is an adequate solution to this, without any plugin?

```js
$('th').click(function() {
  var rows = $('tr');

  rows.eq(0).find('td').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ? 1 : -1;
  }).each(function(newIndex) {
    var originalIndex = $(this).index();
    rows.each(function() {
      var td = $(this).find('td');
      if (originalIndex !== newIndex)
        td.eq(originalIndex).insertAfter(td.eq(newIndex));
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <td>Golden Watch</td>
    <td>Silver Watch</td>
    <td>Car 2018</td>
    <td>Wooden Table</td>
    <td>Sport Car 2019</td>
    <td>Perfume</td>
    <td>Car 2010</td>
    <td>Piano</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price($)</th>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>100000</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td>250000</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Origin Country</th>
    <td>Switzerland</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>England</td>
    <td>Austria</td>

</table>
```

Comment: Keep same column relationships? If so what should be primary sort...top row?

Comment: To sort the numbers you need to make them numeric and not string since 5000 is greater than 10000 alphabetically

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, the same relationships. It should sort the row, with the header clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the version of a solution I came up with.

1. The first thing it does is grabs all the data from the table and loads it into a variable, so we only have to fetch all that data from the page once.
2. The next thing it does is creates the click event listener.  I made it a delegate since I am replacing the `tr` elements all together.

   1. First thing the event listener does is checks to see which `th` was clicked by what its innerHTML is.  If it's one of the string fields, I did a localeCompare on the strings.  Otherwise if it is the numeric price, I simply subtracted them for the sorting.
   2. The last thing I do is replace the entire contents of the table with new rows.  The new rows are generated from the sorted data.  I chose to replace the entire contents of the table with the generated new rows, as the new rows are constructed in a DOM Fragment, and the only touch point with the DOM at that point is the single replacement of all the children of the table.  So it's more performant than replacing one row at a time, or updating one column of each row at a time.

```js
var $tableRows = $('#myTable tr');
var preloadData = $tableRows.first().find('td').map(function(index){
  return {
    product: $tableRows.eq(0).find('td').eq(index).html().trim()
    , price: parseInt($tableRows.eq(1).find('td').eq(index).html().trim(), 10)
    , originCountry: $tableRows.eq(2).find('td').eq(index).html().trim()
  }
}).get();

$(document).on('click', '#myTable tr', function(e){
  var sortDesc = e.target.classList.contains('asc');
  var sortingRow
  
  if (e.target.innerHTML === 'Product') {
    sortingRow = 0;
    
    preloadData.sort(function(a, b){
      if (sortDesc) return b.product.localeCompare(a.product);
      
      return a.product.localeCompare(b.product);
    });
  } else if (e.target.innerHTML === 'Price($)') {
    sortingRow = 1;
    
    preloadData.sort(function(a, b){
      if (sortDesc) return b.price - a.price;
      
      return a.price - b.price;
    });
  } else {
    sortingRow = 2;
    
    preloadData.sort(function(a, b){
      if (sortDesc) return b.originCountry.localeCompare(a.originCountry);
      
      return a.originCountry.localeCompare(b.originCountry);
    });
  }
  
  $('#myTable').html(
    preloadData.reduce(function($rows, columnData, index){
      if (index < 1) {
        $rows.eq(0).append('<th>Product</th>');
        $rows.eq(1).append('<th>Price($)</th>');
        $rows.eq(2).append('<th>Origin Country</th>');
        
        if (!sortDesc) $rows.eq(sortingRow).find('th').addClass('asc');
      }
      
      $rows.eq(0).append('<td>'+ columnData.product +'</td>');
      $rows.eq(1).append('<td>'+ columnData.price +'</td>');
      $rows.eq(2).append('<td>'+ columnData.originCountry +'</td>');
      
      return $rows;
    }, $('<tr><tr><tr>'))
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <td>Golden Watch</td>
    <td>Silver Watch</td>
    <td>Car 2018</td>
    <td>Wooden Table</td>
    <td>Sport Car 2019</td>
    <td>Perfume</td>
    <td>Car 2010</td>
    <td>Piano</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price($)</th>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>100000</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td>250000</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Origin Country</th>
    <td>Switzerland</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>England</td>
    <td>Austria</td>

</table>
```

Edit: Adding the setting of an `asc` class on the row that was sorted ascending.  Should it be clicked a second time, it will flip to sort descending.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic approach that doesn't care how many rows or what the labeling is.

It first creates array of rowData where each sub array is array of objects with original column number and text from each cell. While creating this; a data attribute is added to each cell so it knows it's permanent column number to be used to keep column relationships

These are what first get sorted so an object can be created to store original column number with new sort index. Then as each row of cells gets sorted

```js
// store row data arrays for easy sorting
var rowData = $('tr').map(function(rIdx, row) {
  return [$(row).children('td').map(function(cIdx, cell) {
    // store col # on each cell to use later for matching column sort order
    $(cell).data('col', cIdx + 1);
    // these objects used to keep original column numbers with sorted text
    return {
      col: cIdx + 1,
      text: cell.textContent
    }
  }).get()];
}).get();

var $th=$('#myTable th'),
  $rows = $('#myTable tr');


$th.click(function() {
   var $cell = $(this),
   rIdx = $cell.parent().index(),
   isSorted = $cell.hasClass('sorted'),
   dir = isSorted ? $cell.hasClass('asc') ? 'dsc':'asc' :'asc';
   
   $cell.removeClass('asc dsc').addClass('sorted '+ dir);  
  
   $th.not(this).removeClass('sorted asc dsc');  
 
  $rows.each(function() {
    var sortedCells = $(this).children('td').sort(rowCellSorter(rIdx, dir));
    $(this).append(sortedCells)
  });
});

function rowCellSorter(rIdx, dir) {
  var sortOrder = getSorterOrder(rIdx, dir);
  return function(a, b) {
    var aCol = $(a).data('col'),
      bCol = $(b).data('col')
    return sortOrder[aCol] - sortOrder[bCol]
  }
}

function getSorterOrder(rIdx, dir) {
  var dataRow = rowData[rIdx].slice().sort(dataRowSorter);
  
  if(dir === 'dsc'){
      dataRow.reverse()
  }
  // object with column num as keys, sort index as values
  return dataRow.reduce(function(a, c, i) {
    a[c.col] = i;
    return a;
  }, {});

}

function dataRowSorter(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a.text)) { // text sort
    return a.text.localeCompare(b.text)
  } else { // num sort
    return a.text - b.text
  }
}
```

```css
.asc:after{
  content:' > '
}

.dsc:after{
  content:' < '
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <td>Golden Watch</td>
    <td>Silver Watch</td>
    <td>Car 2018</td>
    <td>Wooden Table</td>
    <td>Sport Car 2019</td>
    <td>Perfume</td>
    <td>Car 2010</td>
    <td>Piano</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price($)</th>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>100000</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td>250000</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Origin Country</th>
    <td>Switzerland</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>England</td>
    <td>Austria</td>

</table>
```